# Disposable items in a class

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

Here is a class that I have created. It currently returns an exception stating that it is in a loop - this is obvious now.

```
public class dirSearch : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    public bool searchSuccessful;
    public string errStr;

    List<string> resList = new List<string>();
    public void getEmpDetails(string filStr, string varStr)
    {
        string strServerDNS = "ldap.<redacted>.com:389";
        string strSearchBaseDN = "ou=People,o=<redacted>.com";
        string strLDAPPath = "LDAP://" + strServerDNS + "/" + strSearchBaseDN;
        DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAPPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
        SearchResultCollection results;

        searcher.Filter = "(uid=" + filStr + ")";
        //make sure the order of the search is like so:
        //UID
        //empnum
        //full name
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(varStr);

        try
        {
            results = searcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                string temStr = result.Properties[varStr][0].ToString();
                resList.Add(temStr);
                searchSuccessful = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errStr = e.ToString();
            searchSuccessful = false;
        }
    }

    public void getEmpDetails(string uid)
    {
        string strLDAPServerAndPort = "ldap.<redacted>.com";
        string strDNPrefix = "uid=" + uid + ", ";
        string strLDAPContainer = "ou=people, o=<redacted>.com";

        string strLDAPPath = "LDAP://" + strLDAPServerAndPort + "/" + strDNPrefix + strLDAPContainer;

        DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAPPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
        SearchResultCollection results;

        searcher.Filter = "(uid=" + uid + ")";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");

        //need conditions here for searching for more than one value, such as <redacted>Manager etc
        try
        {
            results = searcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                string temStr = result.Properties["uid"][0].ToString();
                resList.Add(temStr);
                searchSuccessful = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errStr = e.ToString();
            searchSuccessful = false;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (errStr != null)
                {
                    Dispose();
                }
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

As far as I am aware, the only two (technically) disposable objects here are the string and the list. Is this correct? Or, is there more, less, or other items entirely that I would be disposing of? Furthermore, what specifically makes them "Disposable" objects? Is it the fact that they are single objects that I have instantiated?

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: No, you haven't `IDisposable` fields within `dirSearch` class at all. `String` and `List<String>` don't implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Disposable objects implement IDisposable. This is needed for object that cannot wait for the garbage collector to be destroyed (e.g. file handles).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko so I cannot by definition use this class in a `using` statement unless I add a placeholder disposable type?

Comment: Yet another problem with your implementation is *Stack Overflow*: `Dispose(bool disposing)` calls `Dispose()` which in turn calls `Dispose(bool disposing)`.

Comment: @Wolfish: you can't use `String` as well as `List<String>` in `using`, i.e. `using (String myString = ...)` is a *compile time error*. However, you can implement `IDisposable` in your custom classes, even if this imeplementation is *redundant*.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I'll keep that in mind. I'm not using this specific class in a `using` statement, however I would have to redact so much of the other class in question as to render it unintelligible. Disregarding the `List<string>` and `String` objects, would I need a placeholder object?

Comment: You don't *need* a disposable object inside your class to be able to make your parent class disposable, but if you have nothing internally to dispose of, then why both making the parent disposable. How many times can I say dispose in 1 sentence? Dispose...

Comment: You need to stop doing `catch (Exception e)`. It's a bad practice. You might as well use `goto` in your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity Isn't this a bit too much code for a question?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what the actual question is here...

Comment: @IanKemp I had some problems understanding why some objects should have implemented IDisposable, however it has now become "Is my understanding of IDisposable correct?"

Comment: @Wolfish - There isn't really a limit for "too much" code. You need to post [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code. However much that is, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we implement `IDisposable` when we have *something to dispose* (i.e. *unmanaged resources* like files, RDBMS connections, other `IDisposable` instances etc.). Technically, the implementation could be something like that:

```
// Now IDisposable is redundant: there're no fields to dispose
public class DirSearch : IDisposable {
  // All these three fields don't implement iDisposable thus they can't be disposed
  //TODO: change this field into (read-only) property
  public bool searchSuccessful;

  //TODO: change this field into (read-only) property 
  public string errStr;

  List<string> resList = new List<string>();
  // I've omitted some code
  ...

  // Property: you may want to know if the instance has been dispose or not
  public Boolean IsDisposed {
    get;
    protected set; // or even "private"
  }

  // "protected virtual" since this method should be able to be overridden in child classes
  protected virtual Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
    if (IsDisposed)
      return;

    if (disposing) {
      //TODO: Dispose unmanaged resources here
      // NO Dispose() call here! Beware Stack overflow
    }

    IsDisposed = true;
  }

  public Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
}
```

However, more *natural* is to *remove all* the `IDisposable` stuff from the current `DirSearch` implementation. If you want to use `DirSearch` as *placeholder*, if I understand you right as a *base class* for searches, you'd rather change `DirSearch` into something like `BaseSearch` and make it `abstract`.